# Bootstrap carousel crashes when trying to skip index

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to skip `index(0)` on my carousel with:

```
    $('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    if($('#carousel').carousel(0)){
        $('#carousel').carousel(1);
    }
    });
```

But it crashes when I load the page. I am trying to use a few different functions found on the [bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) to make it do this, but I seem to be doing it incorrectly. Any ideas why this would crash?

I am trying to catch the slide event and say "if the carousel goes to slide 0, send it to slide 1". If this is indeed an infinite loop, could you recommend a way to do this?

**Crash**

[image]

Comment: Assuming carousel like many other jQuery setters returns a jQuery object, your `if` statement is always `true` and this is an infinite loop, so a _crash_.

Comment: @undefined If this is indeed an infinite loop, could you recommend a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming carousel like many other jQuery setters returns a jQuery object, your if statement is always `true` and this is an infinite loop, so a crash. I haven't used the `carousel` method but if you want to check to see whether the first item is currently active you can select the active item and check it's index:

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    if ( $('#carousel .carousel-inner > .item.active').index() === 0 ) 
    {
        $('#carousel').carousel(1);
    }
});
```

The above query assumes your HTML structure is similar to the Bootstrap doc's example.

Comment: This does not work either, it seems to run indefinitely (I added a log to the function and it just repeats hundreds of times).

Comment: I want to give you credit since you pointed me in the right direction. Change `on('slide.bs.carousel',` to `on('slid.bs.carousel',` and it works.

Comment: @JordanD I'm glad that the problem has been solved. Feel free to update the answer.